# Why was the 3d Button in Firefox 30.0 removed?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Does anyone know why the 3D view Button in the top of the developer tools is gone? Is there a way to re-activate it or was it removed permanetly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 31.0 : the button is still here, you may have to enable it in "tool options" before using it

Comment: ups, I didn't check the options there, Sorry. Yes there is it.

Comment: A screenshot, for posterity: http://note.io/1y1ZbVG

Comment: ...it was disabled by default because it is not used by a lot of people.

Comment: If you're using firefox 40 (nightly) and can't find the button, try disabling e10s.